# 'Subsystems' object has no attribute 'rcp'

Tags: volttron

Any chance I could get a tip on how to debug this error in the volttron.log file? `'Subsystems' object has no attribute 'rcp'` what does this mean?

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lib/volttron/volttron/platform/vip/agent/core.py", line 117, in _loop
    method(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/home/volttron/.volttron/agents/4f27247d-e6bf-4e30-8ffe-6d895ac52047/setteroccvavagent-0.1/setteroccvav/agent.py", line 222, in raise_setpoints_up
    result = self.vip.rcp.call('platform.actuator', 'set_multiple_points', self.core.identity, topic_values).get(timeout=30)
AttributeError: 'Subsystems' object has no attribute 'rcp'
```

My agent code with the function running:

```
# now we can send our set_multiple_points request, use the basic form with our additional params

result = self.vip.rcp.call('platform.actuator', 'set_multiple_points', self.core.identity, topic_values).get(timeout=3)
```

This is a [gist](https://gist.github.com/bbartling/6fd63cc957f374fc7b871b27de4eb5d7#file-setteragent-py) of my agent code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a typo, now fixed in the original post.

```
result = self.vip.rpc.call('platform.actuator', 'set_multiple_points', self.core.identity, topic_values).get(timeout=3)
```